# Using pinctrl-single to map board static pins to itself in Device Tree doesn't work with Beaglebone

Tags: linux, gpio, floating, device-tree

Tried building kernel v5.9 for Beaglebone. There are few GPIOs that need to be set on boot, but the `bone-pinmux-helper` driver is not available in the kernel (not sure). Therefore tried mapping static pins to `pinctrl-single` driver itself but it did not work. */sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl* shows that the configuration is correct but the voltage in GPIO pins seems to be floating.

The example in the `pinctrl-single` kernel documentation is as follows.

```dts
pmx_core: pinmux@4a100040 {
    compatible = "pinctrl-single";
    reg = <0x4a100040 0x0196>;
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    #interrupt-cells = <1>;
    interrupt-controller;
    pinctrl-single,register-width = <16>;
    pinctrl-single,function-mask = <0xffff>;
};

&pmx_core {
    /*
     * map all board specific static pins enabled by the pinctrl driver
     * itself during the boot (or just set them up in the bootloader)
     */
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&board_pins>;

    board_pins: pinmux_board_pins {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <
            0x6c 0xf
            0x6e 0xf
            0x70 0xf
            0x72 0xf
        >;
    };
};
```

Comment: Have you tried to enable `CONFIG_DEBUG_PINCTRL` in the kernel configuration and see what's going on there?

Comment: yes, /sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/44e......pinmux/pins, pingroups show that the pins are in the correct configuration. but they don't behave like that.

Comment: Have you tried to contact Linux kernel upstream for that? (I.e. `linux-gpio@` mailing list)

Comment: Not yet, I'll try mailing them. Thank you for the feedback